# Construction of an embedding of $\mathbb{Z} \cup \{\infty\}$ into $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ be the one-point compactification of the integers $\mathbb{Z}$, construct an embedding of $X$ into the reals $\mathbb{R}$.

I already appreciate your hints/answers. Thanks

Comment: Hint: $1/n \to 0$

Comment: I thought about sending $\infty$ to $0$, and any nonzero integer $n$ to $\frac{1}{n}$, but , where should I send $0$ itself ? Because $embedding$ must be continuous ....

Comment: Well, $0$ is an isolated point of $\mathbb{Z}$, so you can send it anywhere except the places you sent one of the other points to.

Comment: If I send $0$ to an arbitrary place, say $2$, I don't ruin continuity of the map ? maybe not because as you said, $0$ is isolated. I see now , Thanks !

Comment: Every function on discrete space is continuous, so actually you don't have to care much about any finite subset of $\Bbb Z$ when embedding, rather you shall take care of the neighborhood of $\infty$  which is the only topologically interesting thing in compactified $\Bbb Z$, but that @PrahladVaidyanathan suggested how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to make sure that the images $f(k)$ for $k\ne\infty$ form a set with no accumulation points other than $f(\infty)$. The latter should be a limit point of the points $f(k)$ when $|k|\to\infty$. I think the following does work:
$$f(k):=\left\{\eqalign{2\quad&(k=0)\cr 0\quad&(k=\infty)\cr {1\over k}\quad&({\rm otherwise})\cr}\right.$$

Answer (score 3):

As said in comments, note that the structure of $\mathbb{Z}$ like order or ring structure is completely irrelevant from topological view. $\mathbb{Z}$ is just the countable discrete space, same as say $\mathbb{N}$ or $ω$. Its one-point compactification is just $(ω + 1)$, i.e. the convergent sequence (as a space). And it is easy to find a convergent sequence in $\mathbb{R}$.